# TastyPie resources

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I have two resources: UserResource and ChannelResource, as follows:

```
class ChannelResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Channel.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'channels'


class UserResource(ModelResource):
    channels = fields.ToManyField(ChannelResource, 'channels', full=True)
    stories = fields.ToManyField('core.api.StoryResource', 'stories', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'users'
```

I can get user listings and info about a single user (including the channels he owns):

```
http://localhost/api/users/1/?format=json&limit=0
{
  channels: [
  {
    id: 1,
    identifier: "default",
    name: "default",
    resource_uri: "/api/v1/channels/1/"
  }],
  id: 1,
  name: threejeez
}
```

but when I try to get a channel listing for a user, I get an error:

```
http://localhost/api/users/1/channels/?format=json&limit=0
error_message: "Invalid resource lookup data provided (mismatched type)."
```

I can see from the above json that the resource is at api/channels/, but I want it to be at api/users/1/channels. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out. The solution is.... ugh. Anyhow, here it is:

```
def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\d+)/channels%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('get_channels'), name="api_get_channels"),
    ]

def get_channels(self, request, **kwargs):
    basic_bundle = self.build_bundle(request=request)
    obj = self.cached_obj_get(bundle=basic_bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
    channel_resource = UserChannelResource()
    try:
        channel_resource._meta.queryset = obj.channels.all()
    except IndexError:
        channel_resource._meta.queryset = Channel.objects.none()

    return channel_resource.get_list(request)
```